# SCD Type 2 End Date issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, etl, scd

I'm struggling with recording a Slow Changing Dimension (SCD). I have a daily ETL job that registers versions of records based on changes.

The problem is that I'm getting End Dates bigger than the Start Date of the current version. What I should be seeing is that the End Date for the non-current record is at least the day before the Start Date of the current record.

[Instead, this is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmF9E.png)

I know that what's causing this is the ETL job. For some reason, it updates the non-current record EndDate to today's date. Once a record is non-current, it should never have it EndDate changed again.

Can someone point out what I've done wrong in the code?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[UpdateBudget_Hist]
AS
  BEGIN
    Merge Into [dbo].[Budget_Hist] as TargetTable
            Using [dbo].[Budget] as SourceTable
              On TargetTable.ProjectKey = SourceTable.ProjectKey
              AND TargetTable.Titulo = SourceTable.Titulo
              AND TargetTable.DataIns = SourceTable.DataIns
                When Not Matched 
                    Then
                        INSERT 
                        Values ( SourceTable.[ProjectKey]
                                    , SourceTable.[Titulo]
                                    , SourceTable.[ActualCost]
                                    , SourceTable.[BaselineCost]
                                    , SourceTable.[UserIns]
                                    , SourceTable.[DataIns]
                                    , SourceTable.[UserUpd]
                                    , SourceTable.[DataUpd]
                                    , SourceTable.[Designation]
                                    , SourceTable.[Committed]
                                    , GetDate()  -- ChangeStartDate
                                    , Null  -- ChangeEndDate
                                    , 'y' )  -- IsCurrent
                When Matched -- When the matched fields of the row currently being looked at match 
                         -- but the rest does not match...
                         AND ( SourceTable.[ActualCost] <> TargetTable.[ActualCost] 
                         OR SourceTable.[BaselineCost] <> TargetTable.[BaselineCost] 
                         OR SourceTable.[Designation] <> TargetTable.[Designation] 
                         OR SourceTable.[Committed] <> TargetTable.[Committed] ) 
                Then 
                        -- Merge will not allow an insert statement to be used under the MATCHED clause
                        -- So, all we can do at this point is to change the IsCurrent status
                        UPDATE -- change the data in the Target table
                        SET TargetTable.IsCurrent = 'n'  -- IsCurrent
                When Not Matched By Source 
                    Then -- The matched fields are in the Target table, but not the source table
                        -- First, Change the current Matched row
                        UPDATE -- change the data in the Target table (DimCustomers)
                        SET TargetTable.ChangeEndDate = GetDate()  -- ADDED THIS for ChangeEndDate!
                             , TargetTable.IsCurrent = 'n';

    -- Add any Rows that were updated to the table Variable after we 
    -- synchronize any Inserts or Deletes.
    Insert into [dbo].[Budget_Hist]
        (  [ProjectKey]
          ,[Titulo]
          ,[ActualCost]
          ,[BaselineCost]
          ,[UserIns]
          ,[DataIns]
          ,[UserUpd]
          ,[DataUpd]
          ,[Designation]
          ,[Committed]
          ,[ChangeStartDate]
          ,[ChangeEndDate]
          ,[IsCurrent])
        Select [ProjectKey] ,[Titulo],[ActualCost],[BaselineCost],[UserIns],[DataIns],[UserUpd],[DataUpd],[Designation],[Committed], GetDate(), Null, 'y' from [dbo].[Budget]
        Except 
        Select [ProjectKey] ,[Titulo],[ActualCost],[BaselineCost],[UserIns],[DataIns],[UserUpd],[DataUpd],[Designation],[Committed], GetDate(), Null, 'y' from [dbo].[Budget_Hist]
  END
```

This is where I think the issue is, but I don't know how to solve it:

```
                    SET TargetTable.ChangeEndDate = GetDate()  -- ADDED THIS for ChangeEndDate!
                         , TargetTable.IsCurrent = 'n';
```

Comment: Maybe something like: `When Not Matched By Source AND TargetTable.IsCurrent <> 'n'`?

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't remember something so basic. Many thanks HoneyBadger!